# Text translation inside service worker before displaying Notification

Tags: javascript, vue.js, service-worker

I use the following code to display a Push Web Notification.
I need to translate the text contained in the `body.message` key.
I have the country code value in the window object but I can't access to window from service worker.

How to hanlde this translation ?

**service-worker.js:**

```
// Listen for incoming push notifications
self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
    // Extract payload as JSON object, default to empty object
    var data = event.data.json() || {};

    // Extract notification image URL
    var image = data.image || 'https://sdk.pushy.me/web/assets/img/icon.png';

    // Notification title and body
    var title = data.title || '';
    var body = data.message || '';

    // Notification options
    var options = {
        body: body,
        icon: image,
        badge: image,
        data: {
            url: data.url
        }
    };

    // Wait until notification is shown
    event.waitUntil(self.registration.showNotification(title, options));
});
```

Comment: Send a message from the main window to the serviceworker.  https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/service-worker/post-message/

Comment: Please use callback pattern!